# HTTP request 403 status, replicated chrome headers

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, http-headers

Hi I'm trying to webscrape https://cncpts.com/collections/

Code is returning a 403 request status but I can access the site on my browser. Anyone knows if I'm missing anything? or is there something happening in request library that I'm unaware of? Thanks a bunch!

```
import requests

headers = { 'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'sec-ch-ua' : '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile' : '?0',
            'sec-fetch-dest' : 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode' : 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site' : 'none',
            'sec-fetch-user' : '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests' : '1',
            'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.Session()
r.headers.update(headers)
print(r.get("https://cncpts.com/collections/"))
```

Comment: You probably need selenium for this. These things used to be easy but Cloudflare ruined it.

Comment: thank you! saved me a lot of agony in searching the source of the problem. how did you know cloudfare was blocking my request?

Comment: You can see it in the headers and the response body.